# Pausing Diagrams in Beamer

Tags: beamer, diagrams, pause

I have a square diagram of the form

```
\begin{displaymath}
\xymatrix{A \ar[r] & D \ar[d] \\\ B \ar[u] & C \ar[l]}
\end{displaymath}
```

in a beamer presentation. I want to add pauses so that first it will just show A and B, then show C then D. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can for example use `\only<>{}` and `\visible<>{}`. For more information, see "9.3 Commands with Overlay Specifications" of the beamer user guide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{displaymath}
\xymatrix{A \only<2>{\ar[r]} & \visible<2>{D} \only<2>{\ar[d]} \\\ B \ar[u] & \visible<2>{C} \only<2>{\ar[l]}}
\end{displaymath}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]